# What is the Recurrence relation for the following code:

Tags: java, recursion, time, time-complexity, recurrence

The code is as follows:

```
static void fun1(int n)  
{  
   int i = 0;    
   if (n > 1)  
     fun1(n - 1);  
   for (i = 0; i < n; i++)  
     System.out.print(" * ");  
}
```

My answer is:

```
T(n) = { n + 2          : if n <= 1
       { T(n-1) + n + 2 : if n > 1
```

The base case contains one assignment and one comparison (both in constant time) as well as the for loop which runs in linear time.

The recursive case has the same as the base case as well as the recursive call T(n-1).

This is why I think I am correct but there are no answers to this problem so an external voice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer is correct, but it can written in more general way, like this :

```
T(n) = T(n-1) + n + const, if n > 1
T(n) = n + const, if n <= 1
```

And here for `const`  you usually choose value 1, for easier calculation, beacause that doesn't have impact on time complexity.